# how to create train, test & validation split of tf.data.Dataset in tf 2.1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

the following code is copied from :
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images

the code aims to create dataset of images downloaded from the web and stored into folders depending upon their classes, please do refer to the link above for the whole context!

```
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir/'*/*'))

for f in list_ds.take(5):
  print(f.numpy())

def get_label(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  return parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES

def decode_img(img):
  # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  # Use `convert_image_dtype` to convert to floats in the [0,1] range.
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
  # resize the image to the desired size.
  return tf.image.resize(img, [IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT])

def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label

# Set `num_parallel_calls` so multiple images are loaded/processed in parallel.
labeled_ds = list_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

for image, label in labeled_ds.take(1):
  print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
  print("Label: ", label.numpy())

def prepare_for_training(ds, cache=True, shuffle_buffer_size=1000):
  # This is a small dataset, only load it once, and keep it in memory.
  # use `.cache(filename)` to cache preprocessing work for datasets that don't
  # fit in memory.
  if cache:
    if isinstance(cache, str):
      ds = ds.cache(cache)
    else:
      ds = ds.cache()

  ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size)

  # Repeat forever
  ds = ds.repeat()

  ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

  # `prefetch` lets the dataset fetch batches in the background while the model
  # is training.
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

  return ds

train_ds = prepare_for_training(labeled_ds)
```

we are finally left with `train_ds` that is a PreffetchDataset object and contains the entire dataset of images, labels!
How to split `train_ds` into train, test & validation sets to feed it into a model?

Answer (score 0):

After the `ds.repeat()` call the dataset is infinite and splitting an infinte dataset doesn't work very well. Therefore you should split it before the `prepare_training()` call. Like this:

```
labeled_ds = list_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
labeled_ds = labeled_ds.shuffle(10000).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

# Size of dataset
n = sum(1 for _ in labeled_ds)
n_train = int(n * 0.8)
n_valid = int(n * 0.1)
n_test = n - n_train - n_valid

train_ds = labeled_ds.take(n_train)
valid_ds = labeled_ds.skip(n_train).take(n_valid)
test_ds = labeled_ds.skip(n_train + n_valid).take(n_test)
```

The line `n = sum(1 for _ in labeled_ds)` iterates through the dataset once to get its size, then it is 3-way split into 80%/10%/10%.